# Would IT ever need a user's domain password?

Tags: windows, domain

Is there anything a Windows domain administrator might need to do while configuring a workstation for a new user that absolutely can't be done without the user's domain account password? To avoid asking users for their passwords the admin could, theoretically, change the password, log in as the user, and do whatever it is they wanted to do, but would that actually give them any additional permissions that they don't already have by virtue of being a domain administrator?

**UPDATE:**

The answers so far have referred to "tuning" or changing the user's profile. However, there's [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289) article from Microsoft on modifying the default profile which gets applied to users when they log on for the first time and [these instructions](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/03/12/windows-tip-edit-user-registry-of-other-users/) for changing another user's Windows registry settings at any time. What would an admin change while logged in as a user that the admin couldn't change using these or other available techniques that don't involving logging in as the user? Just "logging in as the user" isn't a reason to ask for or change the user's password. I'm looking for a *practical* reason for doing so.

Comment: My suspicion before asking this question was that, twisted though Windows administration may be at times, there was nothing that would be impossible for an admin that would be possible for a less-privileged end user. The motivator for asking for a user's password, or changing their password, and logging in with their account would be inexperience or convenience; either the admin doesn't know how to do something or doesn't want to fiddle with registries and editing configuration files by hand and doesn't have tools available to make the required changes.

Comment: You might want to rewrite this question as at first you ask about user passswords then you change to to logging in as the user at all.  These are 2 seperate issues

Comment: How about installing an application that requires access to the user's Outlook profile (like a CRM app that uses Outlook)?  You're at the mercy of the application developer's installer script.

Comment: @Jim Actually, I tried to head off the password reset avenue in the second sentence of my original question. If you reset a user's password, then you DO now have that user's password. You don't have their OLD password. I was getting vague answers about changing a user's profile, so I provided links showing how you could do that without impersonating the user. I also specifically called out "logging in as the user" as not being an acceptable end goal because that was mentioned in a comment as something you couldn't do without requesting/changing the user's password.

Comment: @gravyface So your answer is "to install poorly written software?" Interesting. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @isaac, no you have the reset password, not the one the users uses and now the fact that you reset the password has been logged, as well as, when the user logs in they are going to notice that their password (which you never had) no longer works

Comment: @IsaacTruett Your answer was moved to a comment because it was not an answer, it was a clarification of your question and a summation of points you already made in several comments. StackOverflow may handle that differently, but here on SF that was clearly "not an answer" and was being voted as such (it hadn't been flagged yet, but it was coming). Therefore, I moved it rather than obliterate the content.

Comment: @Isaac, you seem to have this strange notion that anything that doesn't work they way you think it should must of necessity be poorly written. Let me be the first to say that you are jumping to completely invalid conclusions. As admins we see a much broader range of software and installation situations than a dev ever would.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @John We'll have to agree to disagree about who has the stranger notions. You obviously have a very particular bias yourself and I'm not going to argue over that with you.

Comment: I just got my password asked by IT so that "they can join the PC to the domain", isn't that done with admin's passwords and not user's passwords?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is neither acceptable nor necessary for an administrator to request a user's password.

Under the circumstances where it may be necessary for an administrator to log in as a user (and I don't believe that such circumstances exist), the user should log in and supervise the administrator's activities.

The reason for this is accountability. It is the responsibility of each user to ensure that their password is secure. If malicious activity were traced back to a user's credentials, that user could be held accountable. Therefore they need to ensure that their credentials remain secure.

It is also the responsibility of the organisation to ensure that this is not only adopted, but enforced. There was a legal case where somebody in an organisation sent a malicious email using somebody else's mailbox. The owner of the mailbox was ultimately dismissed. While they argued that they had given their password to someone else, the company insisted that it was their responsibility to maintain the integrity of their credentials, and they were therefore accountable, as was dictated by their company IT policy. This was then overturned by a court when this user proved that there was a culture of password sharing endemic within the organisation. The court ruled that if the company could not be seen to actively enforce their IT policy, they could not rely on it for accountability under these circumstances.

That said there is clearly a gulf between theory and practice. I've contracted for a major multi-national firm that provides, amongst other things, IT advisory services, and as part of the documented procedure for an SOE upgrade we were instructed to request the end user's password.

Personally, I take a hard line approach to this. I don't believe that requesting passwords (or re-setting them to access a user's account) is necessary. If there is a vastly increased workload to get around this, then so be it. It's no excuse to compromise security. I guess I'm just fortunate that I'm not a manager, and so don't have to take responsibility for these decisions when instructed to do so by someone higher up.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that you know what is acceptable or necessary in every conceivable situation on the planet?

Comment: Of course not - if somebody can give me an example to the contrary I'll happily accept it. I'm not talking about every conceivable situation on the planet, but with that said I cannot possibly conceive of any goal which is only achievable by compromising a user's login credentials.

Comment: You say "of course not", which completely invalidates the first sentence of your answer. I suggest you edit it accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I'm taking a scientific approach. Just because the sun has risen every day for the past five billion years does not mean I can say with absolute certainty that it will rise tomorrow. But if you ask me, "will the sun rise tomorrow?", I will say yes without feeling the need to further qualify that. So I take your question regarding "every conceivable situation on the planet" to be an equally hypothetical and abstract qualification.

Comment: there are a whole host of reasons to log in as a user without the  users knowledge or presence (off the to of my head new user setup comes to mind).  Logging in as a user doesn not compromise security so long as the access is traceable.  Taking the hard line, your theory is flawed and conclusion invalid.

Comment: Perhaps we need an ivorytower.stackexchange.com?

Comment: off the to of my head new user setup comes to mind - and your mind obviously is stuck here. New user = "No user has the password", so IT sets up the user, then gives the user the password (who changes immediately). They never ask the user  because - ah the user at this point does not know the password.

Comment: If "No user has the password" , IT should provide the user a "magic link" - a one time link to a place where the user can change the password for the first time, just once. If the user sees the link doesn't allow to change the password, someone has tampered with it so a new one has to be provided. If not, the user will use a password that IT doesn't  know aobut.

Answer (score 18):

Let's be clear: if you're a Domain Admin, you can install a piece of software–a device driver comes to mind–that can literally do anything.  However, it's varying degrees of impractical, ranging from "What's the registry key for the desktop background, again?" all the way up to "And then we hook onto the file read call inside the encrypted-profile layer so as to spoof Firefox into thinking that they have disabled cookies from doubleclick.net".

You're asking for an absolute, and I think that's the wrong way to look at this, because the answer's going to be "You never need the user's password, *really*," which is very misleading.  The reality is that  until Microsoft delivers (or you install third-party software to allow) a capability like *NIX's `su`/`sudo`, you'll never be able to perfectly imitate a user's account for all purposes while maintaining a semblance of sanity, without requiring occasional usage–note I didn't say "disclosure!"–of their password.

Comment: A very fair point. One point I was making in my own summarily deleted answer was that there appears to be a lack of tool support in this area.

Comment: on the point of sudo as far as that goes, the windows security model precludes the use of a sudo type utility, as it means you could run applications in the context of another user without authenticating as that user first (there are ways around it but they all make effort to go around the security model).

Comment: +1 - This answer nicely covers the realities, as well as the theory.

Answer (score 8):

Many of us have worked in environments where password disclosure was required for various reasons. I'll even go so far as to say all of us consider it a bad idea. If such needs to be done, the end user needs to consent to it, not be coerced.

Back in the day, like 1998, my IT department used to request a user's password when we were doing a PC replacement so we could get it set up exactly like they had their old one. Down to the icon locations. As we were in a Novell NetWare environment with no corresponding WinNT domain, changing their network password didn't change their local password so we needed to have that password if we wanted to deliver that level of seamless service.

That was 13 years ago. You specifically asked about Windows Domains. At the job I just left, a large University, it was up to the end user whether or not to disclose a password or be there for whatever work was being done. In other words, the end-user *opted in* to it rather than forced by IT. Certain very busy executive-types high up the org-chart generally had their admin assistant log in for them so it was easy for IT people to slip in (consent had already been delegated).

In Windows, the only way to *hand tune* a user's Profile is to log in as that user. If that profile needs hand-tuning for some reason (a bad uninstall left remains that are getting in the way of a reinstall, or other weird stuff), the IT person will need to log in as that user. This can be done by forcing an administrative password change, having the user disclose their password, or having the user log the IT person in as themselves and letting the IT person work.

Comment: What sort of profile tuning could you do as the user that you couldn't do by modifying the default profile as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289) before the user logs in?

Comment: For the most part, no, there are still things that need to be configured for that specific user. For example, before Outlook 2007/Exchange 2007, you had to configure Outlook manually for that user. Now with autodiscover, you could possibly consider letting them try it themselves, but still, most administrators would not as users just want it to start when they log in.

Comment: @KContreau Microsoft says [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/outlook-e-mail-profiles-explained-HA001147158.aspx) that Outlook profiles are stored in the registry, which an admin can edit from their own account. Any other ideas?

Comment: @IsaacTruett **Technically** everything can be done directly through regedit or hand-editing those desktop.ini files. However, a lot of IT people are far more comfortable with UI tools. As a short-cut, ill-advised though it may be, the IT person may ask a user to do any of the three things I mentioned (login for them, go through a password reset, or give the password) and use the tools they know well, the GUI.

Comment: Issac, while it is stored in the registry, some of the settings are specific, and impossible to edit. You must log in as the user to let the program change them as you create their profile.

Comment: @KCotreau Can you backup your claim that a registry setting can be impossible to edit with a citation?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Could I convince you to update the last paragraph of your answer to reflect your comment above? Otherwise, great answer. +1. Thanks!

Comment: @KCotreau @Isaac **Technically** you could copy their registry hive to the admin's profile temporarily, use whatever's necessary to edit it, then put it back. This is *Not a Good Idea™* in 99% of cases. I know of very few circumstances where knowing the users password is necessary these days; and all of them are related to *dumb* conveniences (like the Netware example SysAdmin1138 gave).

Comment: Use the login script you joker!

Answer (score 5):

Some applications during installation require the ability to make changes or reference the user's profile (i.e. CRM applications that integrate with Outlook) by use of environmental variables like %userprofile%, modifying HK_CURRENT_USER, and the like.

While you could certainly "reverse engineer" an installation with tools like procmon and then manually modify the user's profile, registry, etc. after the fact, this is highly inefficient, impractical, and error prone.

Comment: +1. I could definitely seeing this being a factor. As a software engineer, I would argue that there are better ways to write installation processes than to require the end user to be logged in during installation. There are, in fact, existing software products that allow for different single-user and multi-user installation processes, such as [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=118663).

Comment: @Isaac, I believe you have overlooked the fundamental principle of per user configuration, which cannot be taken care of by the installer. Take for example a package that's going to be used by multiple users on a given machine, where each user needs/wants/requires a different configuration and they need to be in place before those users start using the package.

Comment: @John/Isaac: I'm assuming, John, you're speaking of completing this customization on behalf of the user?  If so, yes, another good point for why you'd want or need to login as the user, especially if the configuration is not modifiable outside of the application (stored in a binary format) and is bound to the currently logged in user.

Comment: that is correct. Resetting the user's password in such a situation merely causes problems, as well as interferes with their ability to do whatever they are currently doing on another machine.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely 100% not. Anything that needs to be done with another users account should be done by resetting the users password, logging in, and then either having the user call the helpdesk or restting the password to something uthe users is told and setting the account to force password to change on next login.  While admit I've worked in fairly large and or secure environments disclosing your password to anyone was usually grounds for termination (and that should be the case in most situations)

Comment: That's too broad a statement. There are many environments where that just won't work. I'd go for maybe 98% but certainly not 100%.

Comment: @John Can you offer a specific example of something that is impossible to do without being logged in as the end user?

Comment: @Isaac: there are many applications that, during installation, reference %userprofile% for file placement, perhaps make changes like installing toolbars in Word or Outlook, etc.  Sure, you could sit there with procmon running, diligently record every registry, profile, etc. change, but why on earth would you bother?

Comment: @john, can you give me an example of where it would be impossible to reset the users password as explained?  I'd agree that there are places where users are too complacent or admins too lazy, but I've yet to encounter a place where that simply could not work.

Comment: @Jim, where I work we frequently need to log on as others and resetting passwords simply pisses people off without good cause. We have an environment where passwords (for most users) are not secret within the company. I know that goes against the grain for anyone who works in larger companies and it was a real culture shock for me when I started here. It's a management choice, not mine, and that's that.

Comment: @john, so in your case you always know the password (as they are not secret), you could reset the password, then set it back to the users non secret password when finished.  Admittedly it seems pointless in your scenario since passwords are public knowledge, but what reason would that not work?

Comment: @Jim, there's the problem of the user being affected as they will normally be working on another machine and/or need to log in elsewhere while I'm doing my thing on the target machine. I need to stress that the users have full knowledge that I'm logging in as them (very often at their request).

Comment: @john the only issue would be a user that logs out or locks their workstation then comes back while you are working on their account on a different workstation, but I agree that your circumstances probably preclude any security concerns by admins logging in as users.  I think however your circumstances throw security out the window.

Comment: @Jim, I couldn't agree more about the lack of security but my case does illustrate that, whether we like it or not, there are exceptions to every rule. Of course perimeter security is entirely another matter and is taken seriously.

Comment: @John, I don't think this exception disproves the rule, when you have a company clearly choosing to blatently ignore security (and if this was the US open up gobs of legal liability on the HR side alone) no normal policies apply.  Ignoring the fact that 2+1<>4 still leaves you 1 shy of 4.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these posts seem quite old, but hopefully some knowledgeable folks are still active on the thread, since this would seem to continue to be a current topic.

Arguments certainly can be made that *you shouldn't ever* have to request a password.  I'd much prefer to tell my users "don't ever share"... and yes, configuration can *in most cases* be handled by an administrator for a user.  But troubleshooting is another affair.

We support a one-to-one program with 2600 students and 500 employees.  We address "weird" software problems on a daily basis.  It is quite often the case that we must experience the problem as the user in order to resolve the issue (or determine with some confidence that a reload is going to be needed).  Absolutely, we try to do this with the user present - but that isn't always practical; they have a schedule to maintain.

What about smartcards?  Is there any feasibility in a 2010/2012 AD Environment that a smartcard could be associated (temporarily) with a domain account?  This would permit access to the user's account in full reality, while not exposing their password specifically.  The card could then be deactivated when the troubleshooting was complete.  Technicians could utilize the account, but the cards could be well supervised.

We've used fingerprint readers for years, but the process for setting that up for a specific tech, then clearing that print simply isn't feasible.  I'm not sure how complex the process would be to "authorize" and then "deactivate" a smart card for a particular user would be, but it seems like it could be a decent compromise.

Comment: StackExchange operates on a different model than traditional forums in that this is not a discussion thread but rather a question followed by a selection of potential answers. On the downside this is also a poor example of a question per our [FAQ].

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Anything that needs to be done to their profile. When that happens, you either must know their password, or set it, as you said. Then they can change it when you are done.

If you log in as that user, you are not giving them additional permissions. You are logging in as them with their permissions.

Comment: beat me to it.  Was thinking of applications that integrate with Outlook especially.

Comment: Yes, obviously you aren't giving the user extra permissions. The question is, what could an admin do with an individual user's permissions that they, the admin, couldn't do with their own admin permissions? So, what would an admin do to a user's profile that they couldn't do from their own admin account?

Comment: The answer to your question what can't the admin do: Simply log in as that user. When that user logs in, only then can changes be made to the profile that is associated with that user. When you log in as administrator, you log in with your administrator profile.

Comment: I thought I misread the question but no you do not need the users password to do anything to the profile.